# React component prop change not triggering useEffect() when inside another library

Tags: reactjs, sapui5, react-functional-component

I have an app using OpenUI5 with some React functional components/hooks inside:

```
private _myReactWindow = window["studioStepComponents"]
private _myReactView;

private someFunction(someNewValue) {
  this._myReactView.someProp = someNewValue;
}

private someRenderFunction() {
  this._myReactView = this._myReactWindow.createElement(this._myReactWindow.MyReactComponent,
    {
      someProp: this.someValue
    });
}
```

createElement is working fine and in "someFunction" I can see the correct values for this._myReactView.someProp, even after setting it to a different value, but the useEffect() hook is not triggering on the React side.  Is there any way I can get it to pick up the change?  I realize these are different frameworks with different bindings but with the value changing I still would have thought React would see the prop change.